# eclipse gradle spring mvc tomcat build

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am learning Spring and using Spring Recipes 3rd edition by Marten Deinum.  I just got to chapter 4 that focuses on spring mvc.  The examples are great except in this chapter they don't tell you how to deploy an imported gradle spring mvc project into a tomcat container.  Any idea on how I should do it?  Normally when deploying a EE Java Dynamic web project you get to define the runtime target -- in my case that would be tomcat v7.0.  I am importing the project and for some reason don't get to describe the target.  Any ideas?

Best Regards,
Steve Mansfield

Comment: Did you try `./gradlew clean war`? The deployable war file should be in the `build/libs` directory.

Comment: I can certainly deploy the war file to tomcat.  I am wondering if eclipse has a built in automatic way of loading tomcat and deploying the application.  Normally I would create a dynamic web project and define tomcat as the runtime target and everything gets deployed automatically.  The examples that I have are gradle builds.  Is there a similar way to deploy the application with these gradle builds or do I have to extract the war file and deploy into tomcat as suggested?

Comment: Wow...I looked for weeks until I stumbled onto this video. Getting spring-gradle to deploy to tomcat using Eclipse is easy...Once you know how. Check out this video and it takes you though step by step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LO40oH5abg Thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 0):

You can set the targeted runtime manually in Eclipse by right clicking on the project -> properties -> Targeted Runtimes -> select the runtime. In your case tomcat v7.0.

I was not able to find an elegant way to do this in gradle. The way I did it was to have the gradle build file add it to the eclipse settings by adding the following to your build.gradle file. You will also need to be using the eclipse-wtp plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'    

eclipse.classpath.file {
        withXml { xml ->
            def node = xml.asNode()
            node.appendNode( 'classpathentry', [ kind: 'con', path: 'org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v8.0'])
            node.appendNode( 'classpathentry', [kind: 'con', path: 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/Jdk8'])
        }
    }
```

where 'Apache Tomcat v8.0' is the targeted runtime, and Jdk8 is the installed JRE in Eclipse that the project is using.

This will add an entry for the container to your projects .classpath file.

Comment: I am new to gradle.  How do I make the changes you suggested above?

Comment: You can add the code block above anywhere in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched this topic for a couple of days. Actually I guess the best way to solve this problem may be: use the gradle plugin gretty as the container to hold your project.
You can simply add the configure like below:

```
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
//Gretty
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
  }
}

gretty {
  httpPort = 8080
  contextPath = '****'
  servletContainer = 'jetty9'
}
```

Then use the task: jettyRun to start the web service. It should be satisfy almost all of your requirement except that you have some special requirement(such as hold multiple project at the same time...).

More information:
You can install the gradle plugin in Eclipse and import your gradle project, then run the task in eclipse to start the service and debug.